# Secure requests to a Webservice via Android

Tags: android, web-services, security, encryption

I've and android application which sends post requests to a web service. I want to secure the communication between the two and was wondering which is the best approach:

1) Make https requests

2) Encrypt the request params via an encryption algorithm and decrypt on the web service (I found this one [SimpleCryto](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_encrypt_and_decrypt_strings.rhtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTTPS.

The problem with novel crypto code is that it doesn't fail obviously.  Your implementation can contain bugs and design flaws that make it completely insecure, *but your application still works* so you don't find out - until it's too late.  On the other hand, if you use HTTPS, you will be using standard protocols and implementations that have been reviewed and tested.

Comment: how to use HTTPS?. Can you write a piece of code for this ?